# Sub-view isn't rendered

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have to work with Backbone.js and I'm experiencing an issue on the rendering of a sub-view.

Here's a quick description of my behavior. I've got packages which contains services. I've got a view for :

- The package list
- A specific package
- The inner service list of a package
- A specific service

Packages and services are stored in collections.

Here's my package view :

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {

        this.mainView = this.options.mainView;
        this.innerEl = '#' + this.model.attributes.packCode + '-includedServices';
        // rendering includedServices using service view
        this.servicesView = new PackServicesView({                
            el : $(this.innerEl),
            mainView : this.mainView,
            collection : this.model.attributes.includedServices,
            packCode : this.model.attributes.packCode
        });

        // Compile template
        this.template = _.template(tmpl);

        /*--- binding ---*/
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');

        this.model.bind('change', this.render);

        /*---------------*/
        this.render();
    }, // initialize

    events : {
        'click input[type=checkbox]' : 'onCheck'
    },
    onCheck : function(event) {
        this.model.toggleSelected();
        this.mainView.setLastClickedPack(this.model);
    },
    render : function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

        this.$el.append(this.servicesView.render().el);

        return this.$el;
    }
});
```

My `PackServicesView` :

```
 Backbone.View.extend({
    //el: 'myIncludedServices',
    initialize: function() {
        this.mainView = this.options.mainView;
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
        this.collection.bind('add', this.addPackService, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
        this.collection.each(this.addPackService, this);
        return this.$el;
    },
    addPackService: function(item) {
        this.$el.append(new PackServiceView({
            model: item,
            mainView: this.mainView
        }).render());
    }

});
```

And my `PackServiceView` :

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {

        this.mainView = this.options.mainView;
        //Compile template
        this.template = _.template(tmpl);
        //Création des sous vue
        this.model.set({
             defaultChoice: this.model.attributes.default
        });
        /*--- binding ---*/
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        /*---------------*/
        this.render();
    }, //initialize
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this.$el;
    },
    events: {
        'click input[type=checkbox]': 'clickEvent'
    },
    clickEvent: function(event) {
        this.model.toggleSelected();
    }
});
```

When debugging with Firefox, I saw that the `render` function of `PackServiceview` is rendering its template fine.

I've got a div in my package template with the id set to `"<%=packCode%>-includedServices"` in order to bind it in the DOM, but from what I've read in different topics, I assume that my issue comes from a DOM attachment issue. As I have more than one `PackView`, I have to set a distinct id on each `PackServicesView`.

A little [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sebvb/Lex3shw9/14/) which reproduce the issue.

Comment: So `'#' + this.model.attributes.packCode + '-includedServices'` is inside the package view template?

Comment: Yes. But not at the "top level" it's inside an other <div>

Comment: Why you empty the  el(this.$el.empty()) in you PackServicesView.render?

Comment: it's a copy/paste of a ServicesView which render services outside of package. I guess the purpose is to refill from scratch the list when we change the displayed data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `$(this.innerEl)` in `PackView.initialize()` the element has not yet been added to the DOM, the call to `this.render();` is several lines later.

I've corrected your JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/uenut4te/

```
    this.render();

    // rendering includedServices using service view
    this.servicesView = new PackServicesView({                
        el : $(this.innerEl),
        collection : this.model.get('services'),
        packCode : this.model.get('packCode')
    });
```

I've changed the order so that the PackView renders before the PackServicesView is instantiated.